# why doesn't my .gitconfig work? (for external diff)

Tags: git, shell, diff, macvim

I added this in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[diff]
    external = mvimdiff

[difftool]
    prompt = false
```

and made a 755 `/bin/mvimdiff` that:

```
#!/bin/sh

mvim -d "$2" "$5"
```

in order to invoke MacVim as my git diff tool. But when I run command `git diff` in a git folder, it still output the result from normal `diff` to shell. No MacVim at all. I am sure that no `.git/config` overwrite the `.gitconfig`, and I have tried to restart my computer to refresh. Why doesn't the config work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be better off using `git difftool` to invoke an “interactive” diff tool. For example:

Adapt the built-in `gvimdiff` tool to `mvim`:

```
git config --global diff.tool gvimdiff
git config --global difftool.gvimdiff.path mvim
```

Or, configure `mvimdiff` from scratch:

```
git config --global diff.tool mvimdiff
git config --global difftool.mvimdiff.cmd 'mvim -f -d "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
```

Then run `git difftool` to view the each differing file in *MacVim*.

---

If you really want `git diff` itself to use *MacVim*, then you can configure it like this (without any external script files):

```
git config diff.external 'd() { mvim -f -d "$2" "$5"; }; d'
```

---

Either way, you need to make sure that the appropriate `mvim` is in your PATH. Also, you will need to use the `-f` option (“do not fork”/“run in foreground”) because otherwise `git diff` will probably delete the temporary files before *MacVim* has had a chance to read them (at least one file from each invocation will be a temporary file).

Comment: still doesn't work for me :(➜  

✗ git config --global diff.tool meld
✗ git config --global difftool.meld.cmd 'meld "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
✗ git difftool env-context.xml
diff --cc env-context.xml
index 4f430b5,b7ab2ef..0000000....